# Where did C#'s attributes come from?

Tags: c#, properties, attributes, annotations, history

I find C#'s Attributes, Python's Properties too a really nice idea, and I guess their direct ancestor might have come from Java's Annotations, but I'm curious as to where this concept originally came from, anyone has any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an old concept, metadata. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445332/what-was-the-historical-precursor-for-net-attributes) question, it's the same of yours.